Safety of docx2pdf and pdf2docx
I have a question about the safety of dox2pdf and pdf2docx. Have you heard of any safety issues with their use? I would like to use them only for my own purposes and I wonder if they collect converted files. I checked them on PyPI and GitHub and didn't notice any problems, but I would like to hear your opinions.
###Script:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from docx2pdf import convert
from pdf2docx import Converter

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Document Converter")
    root.geometry("300x100")
    
    def choose_file(filetypes):
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=filetypes)
        return file
    
    def convert_to_pdf():
        file_path = choose_file([("DOCX files", "*.docx"), ("All files", "*.*")])
        if file_path:
            try:
                convert(file_path)
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Converted to PDF: {file_path}")
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Conversion to PDF failed: {e}")
    
    def convert_to_docx():
        file_path = choose_file([("PDF files", "*.pdf"), ("All files", "*.*")])
        if file_path:
            try:
                docx_file = file_path.replace('.pdf', '.docx')
                cv = Converter(file_path)
                cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
                cv.close()
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Converted to DOCX: {docx_file}")
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Conversion to DOCX failed: {e}")
    
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Convert DOCX to PDF', command=convert_to_pdf)
    b1.pack(pady=5)
    
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Convert PDF to DOCX', command=convert_to_docx)
    b2.pack(pady=5)
    
    root.mainloop()

I have examined PyPI, GitHub and sourcecode, but I would like to know what You are thinking about these issue

Safety in what sense? These are complex formats that probably do have lots of funny corner cases, so if you’re worried about them handling potentially malicious user input, stick the script in a VM or a tightly locked down container for isolation.
